# How to make my VB script overwrite the existing Shortcut file instead of creating a duplicate

Tags: vbscript

I am using the following VB Script to update the target location & add arguments to it.

```
Set wsc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Soft.LNK") 

lnk.targetpath = "C:\Soft\bin\Soft.exe" 
lnk.Arguments = "-user:App -passwd:App1" 
lnk.save
```

The script works fine only that it creates another (duplicate) shortcut file instead of just updating the existing file.

I call this vb script from another batch file

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: You are able to create two lnk files in the Desktop folder? Are you sure they have the exact same name?

Comment: I can't help you with code but mybe you could delete the old one before you make the new one.or somthing like that.

Comment: I was wrong, it is indeed creating a duplicate. Please have a look at the updated script.

Answer (score 1):

The elements you see in the desktop are stored in different folders.

Assuming that there are two shortcuts with the same name, i will bet each shortcut is placed in a different folder. The one you are creating with your code will be placed in the desktop folder of the current user and the previous one in a shared folder.

You can not overwrite the existing shortcut if the path used to open it point to another folder. Check in the properties of the shortcut, inside the *"General"* tab, where the shortcuts are stored.

The most probable solution is

```
Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop") & "\Soft.LNK")
```